# Failing to install Apache Airflow in WSL due to pip version/python version error

Tags: python, pip, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot install Apache Airflow on my Windows10 WSL due to error below :

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
```

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-h36n9pdt/cryptography/
```

command :

```
export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
python3 -m pip install apache-airflow
```

even made sure python version is >3.5 and pip is also showing that :

python-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5).

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to newer Ubuntu on WSL2. The version of PIP is REALLY old on this old Ubuntu box and this is the problem.

If you install new Airflow version you need latest PIP (it works best), the rust problem you have is precisely because `cryptography` package needs new version of pip to build.

Another problem is that your installation command is wrong:

`export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes`

1. The SLUGIFY command is not needed for > 2 years now. You can remove it.

`python3 -m pip install apache-airflow`

2. The official installation should use constraints as specified in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html